# Google: What does a return to PR 'Unranked' mean?

Tags: google, pagerank

One of my sites is very new (about 3 months).  When first launched its pages had (unsurprisingly) a Google PR of 'Unranked' [From Google toolbar stats, via the firefox SearchStatus plugin].  After a few weeks these changed to PR0.  Just recently I noticed that they are showing PR 'Unranked' once more in Google Toolbar.

As far as I know I'm following the Google guidelines.  Results for the site still seem to be showing for its keywords.

**What could this mean?**

Comment: Just wait and see.... what happens with you PR?

Answer (score 1):

PageRank is just one of the (200+) factors used to place you in search results, so even though it's got worse you're still doing well on the other factors.

It could be that the links to your site (which give you PageRank) were removed so that you went from PR0 to Unranked.

Comment: But is Unranked part of the normal PageRank scale? I though this was some sort of special status, that you could not get just by loosing PR.  The strange thing is that my links have increased, not reduced.

Comment: N/A PageRank may means that your site/pages have gotten a penalty from Google.